# Force https with vue history in apache

Tags: .htaccess, vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to force https connection through .htaccess in apache for vue.js history:

Vue history requires .htaccess like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

How can I modify this .htaccess to force SSL connection?

Answer (score 9):

Line 3 and 4 are for redirecting to https.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok. Sorry. Your code reminds me of a Wordpress .htaccess. Is that right?

Comment: Please read description - I need this .htaccess and rules for vue.js

Comment: hmm, strange, could you describe the loop and perhaps give some more information about your setup?

Comment: All is in my post actually

Comment: No, I did not :/

Comment: Ok. Just updated my answer, but just found out that there is still one problem. It would redirect from http://example.com/ to https://example.com/index.html. I'll see if I find something better :)

Comment: Ok, just ignore my previous comment. That was an issue I got because I had and nginx as reverse proxy in my setup. I tested the code which is in my answer with only apache 2.4.29 now and it works for me. If you get a loop with it, then the problem lies elsewhere and it would be good to get more information regarding your environment for solving the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but this what I'm using to force ssl in vue

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```